# how do I actually use app access token with facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I set up app secret and id, can retrieve access token through a GET request in a form of "app_id|seemingly_my_access_token" - but then how do I actually use it? When I tried it like this

```
        new GraphRequest(new AccessToken("seemingly_my_access_token", "app_id", "app_id", null, null, null, null, null),
                            "/the_site_i_want_to_retrieve_name/feed",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                                    mTextView.setText(response.toString() + " \n");
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
```

, I get 400 response (OAuthException - invalid OAuth access token). What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: after a couple of builds GraphRequest no longer worked (always throwing some mysterious errors), so I decided to use just plain REST queries to Graph API (this time using Volley library).

**Before**: with trial and error I eventually stumbled upon the solution. The tricky part was constructing AccessToken object from the retrieved string:

```
new AccessToken("app_id|seemingly_my_access_token",
                "app_id", "app_id", null, null, null, null, null)
```

I am posting this since it was not obvious for me and I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere.